# How to inject DbContext in MVC 6 using default dependency injection?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Can you please tell me how to inject a dbContext using the default dependency injection in MVC 6? Do I just need to create an interface and add it in the Startup.cs as below?

`services.AddTransient<IMyDb, MyDb>();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that should be enough. Then, as part of the controller parameters, add the interface and it will be injected:

```cs
class MyController
{
    public MyController(IMyDb dbContext)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I inject it in a static class? Static class should have a parameter-less constructor ?

Comment: You don't :) Use non-static classes and/or factories

Answer (score 1):

you can inject the concrete type

```
public MyController(MyDb dbContext)
```